# How to extend an ImageField in my own django admin template?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-models

I would like to make a custom admin page for one of my application with django. I've created a change_form.html and fieldset.html in admin/myapp/mymodel of my template folder. I am now able to customize the page.

mymodel has an ImageField and I would like to display this image on the page. I guess this is possible because the ImageField shows a link to the image on the page.

I am trying to modify the fieldset.html but unfortunately I don't know how to access the url in order to put in an img html tag. `{{field.field.field}}` shows an ImageField object but how to access the current value for this field?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The current object can be accessed in a custom django admin template with `{{original}}`

It solves my problem

Answer (score 3):

```
<img src="{{field.field.field.url}}">
```

On a related note, instead of having to do all that, you could use [django-form-utils](http://github.com/carljm/django-form-utils) that will provide you a thumbnail included display and clear-able file field, for free.